# Debugging! Program won't run

Tags: c, debugging, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a c program which will wait for me to hit a key on a 4x4 keypad and then display the number I have hit. The program I have bit runs but ends just as soon as I start it and I can't find my mistake.

```
 #include <wiringPi.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 #define COL1     11
 #define COL2     10
 #define COL3     6
 #define COL4     5
 #define ROW1     4
 #define ROW2     3
 #define ROW3     2
 #define ROW4     1

 #define DET      0

 int colnum;
 int rownum;

 int keyinterrupt (void)
 {
      int col[] = {COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4};
      int row[] = {ROW1, ROW2, ROW3, ROW4};
      int reset;
      for(colnum = 0; colnum++; colnum < 4)
      {
           for(reset = 0; reset++; reset < 4)
           {
                digitalWrite(col[reset], 0);
           }

           digitalWrite(col[colnum], 1);

           for(rownum = 0; rownum++; rownum < 4)
           {
                if(digitalRead(row[rownum]))
                {return 0;}
           }
      }
 }

 int main (void)
 {
      pinMode(COL1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(COL2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(COL3, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(COL4, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ROW1, INPUT);
      pinMode(ROW2, INPUT);
      pinMode(ROW3, INPUT);
      pinMode(ROW4, INPUT);

      if(wiringPiISR (DET, INT_EDGE_RISING, &keyinterrupt) < 0)
      {
           printf("Unable to setup ISR");
           return 1;
      }

      while(1)
      {
           while(!DET)
           {
                delay(1);
           }

           printf("The key pressed was at Col:%i Row:%i", colnum, rownum);
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You will get down voted if you just asking for people to review you code.  Questions should be more focused and specific.

Comment: I am new here and didn't know that. I have been stuck on this for ages now but I will keep trying. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the inclusion of \n makes a big difference in displaying information. My code was theoretically correct (apart from syntax errors) but I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

You've mixed up your `for` loop syntax three times.

```
for(colnum = 0; colnum++; colnum < 4)
```

The *second* entry should be the condition, and the third is the thing to do at the end of each iteration:

```
for (colnum = 0; colnum < 4; colnum++)
```

Comment: Good spot! When you look at your own code you don't see these sort of mistakes (FYI - I am new to c). Still didn't help my program run though.